# Rows in one table are ordered randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently developing an application which is saving data on a Microsoft SQL Server. While testing I noticed that in one table the rows are seemingly ordered randomly while in all other tables they are sorted by their primary key, which is an autoincrementing integer.

Example:

Ordered table:

[image: Ordered Table]

Random order:

[image]

I know that I can order them in the SQL query so this is not my problem.

My question: Is there a reason why they are ordered differently?

Edit: Someone wanted to see the `CREATE TABLE` statements

Ordered table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Label](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [XmlTemplatePath] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Label] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_Label_XmlTemplatePath] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [XmlTemplatePath] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Unordered table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parameter](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Parameter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_Parameter_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want the results in a particular order, then use `ORDER BY`.  If you have a clustered index, then ordering by the keys in that index should be quite fast.

Comment: Rows in  a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted. Without an `order by`  the DBMS is free to return them in any order it likes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "any order it likes" = the fastest way it can (which can vary between executions of the same query).

Comment: usually (not always), if your autonumber is a clustered primary key, it will return in that order. Check to see if the PK on the seemingly unordered table is a clustered one.

Comment: While I do agree tables are not ordered, I have never seen a table in SQL Server return out of primary key order if an auto increment is used, which is what the OP is asking. Can you edit the question and post the table definitions *(`CREATE TABLE`)*?

Comment: @Jeremy The primary keys in both tables are clustered.

Comment: Do they both have `Identity Specification` defined? *I wouldn't have to ask this if you'd just post the table definitions to the question.*

Comment: @Lankymart I added the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: The order in your second table is not random: it's ordered on the name column.

Comment: @StephaneM You are right, I added more rows to be sure and it is indeed ordered alphabetically. I am still wondering why it only does this on this table. Could this be because of the `UNIQUE` constraint? Even though there is one in both tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server generally strives to return data as efficiently as possible which may or may not be in order of the clustered index.  Examine your execution plan to see what index is used and how it is scanned.

Consider this example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Demo
    ON
          (NAME='Demo_Primary1', FILENAME='C:\SqlDataFiles\Demo_Primary', SIZE=10MB)
        , (NAME='Demo_Primary2', FILENAME='D:\SqlDataFiles\Demo_Primary2', SIZE=10MB)
    LOG ON
          (NAME='Demo_Log', FILENAME='D:\SqlLogFiles\Demo_Log.ldf', SIZE=1MB);
GO

USE Demo;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parameter]
    (
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                 NOT NULL
    , [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_Parameter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    , CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_Parameter_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( [Name] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
GO

WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num
        FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d CROSS JOIN t4 AS e)
INSERT INTO dbo.Parameter WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT CAST(num AS char(255))
FROM t1K
WHERE num BETWEEN 1 AND 256;
GO
WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num
        FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d CROSS JOIN t4 AS e)
INSERT INTO dbo.Parameter WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT CAST(num AS char(255))
FROM t1K
WHERE num BETWEEN 257 AND 512;
GO
WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num
        FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d CROSS JOIN t4 AS e)
INSERT INTO dbo.Parameter WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT CAST(num AS char(255))
FROM t1K
WHERE num BETWEEN 513 AND 768;
GO
WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num
        FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d CROSS JOIN t4 AS e)
INSERT INTO dbo.Parameter WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT CAST(num AS char(255))
FROM t1K
WHERE num BETWEEN 769 AND 1024;
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.Parameter;
GO
```

On my SQL 2014 system, I see results are not returned in order by the identity values even though the clustered index is scanned.  The clustered index scan operator in the execution plan shows `Ordered False`.  SQL Server chose to scan the table in allocation order in this case rather than follow the logical order of the page linkage because read integrity isn't needed in the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level.

Even in other isolation levels, SQL Server may choose to scan a different index which will also result in an order different than the identity values.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the execution plan as you suggested and while the ordered result used a clustered index scan on the primary key column, the unordered result used a nonclustered one on the `Name` column with the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Without an `ORDER BY` statement the records will be returned in an order that depends on the query plan produced.

In the first case you are returning three columns and your unique index doesn't contain all of them. Therefore this won't be used and the query will scan the primary key.

In the second case you are returning two columns and the unique index contains both of them (note that the clustered index key is always included in an index - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx) so this is a smaller and therefore quicker index to use than the primary key, which would mean reading the whole row to get your data.

In summary, the second query can use the unique index as a covering index, the first can't.